# setImageResource always gives out OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am trying to create a ListView with card_layout which takes in ImageView And 3 TextViews:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/book_cover"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_author"
        style="@style/subheading_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_title"
        style="@style/heading_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_completion_status"
        style="@style/third_heading_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Filling the card with CardItem objects

```
public class CardItem
{
private String bookAuthor;
private String bookTitle;
private String bookCompletionStatus;
private int bookCoverResID;

/*
* Constructors
*/
public CardItem(String bookTitle)
{
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    bookCoverResID = 0;
}

public CardItem(String bookTitle, String bookAuthor, String bookCompletionStatus)
{
    this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    this.bookCompletionStatus = bookCompletionStatus;
    bookCoverResID = 0;
}

public CardItem(String bookTitle, String bookAuthor, String bookCompletionStatus, int bookCoverResID)
{
    this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    this.bookCompletionStatus = bookCompletionStatus;
    this.bookCoverResID = bookCoverResID;
}

/*
* Getters and Setters
*/
public String getBookAuthor() {
    return bookAuthor;
}

public void setBookAuthor(String bookAuthor) {
    this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
}

public String getBookTitle() {
    return bookTitle;
}

public void setBookTitle(String bookTitle) {
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
}

public int getBookCoverResID() {
    return bookCoverResID;
}

public void setBookCoverResID(int bookCoverResID) {
    this.bookCoverResID = bookCoverResID;
}

public String getBookCompletionStatus() {
    return bookCompletionStatus;
}

public void setBookCompletionStatus(String bookCompletionStatus) {
    this.bookCompletionStatus = bookCompletionStatus;
}

/*
* misc. methods
*/
public boolean hasBookCover()
{
    return (bookCoverResID!=0);
}
}
```

And using a CardItemAdapter to fill listview

```
public class CardItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CardItem>
{
public CardItemAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<CardItem> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
{
    View tempView = convertView;
    if(tempView == null)
        tempView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate( R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);

    TextView bookAuthor = tempView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
    TextView bookTitle = tempView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
    TextView bookCompletionStatus = tempView.findViewById(R.id.book_completion_status);
    ImageView bookCover = tempView.findViewById(R.id.book_cover);

    bookTitle.setText(getItem(position).getBookTitle());

    if(bookAuthor != null)
        bookAuthor.setText(getItem(position).getBookAuthor());

    if(bookCompletionStatus != null)
        bookCompletionStatus.setText(getItem(position).getBookCompletionStatus());


    if(getItem(position).hasBookCover())
        bookCover.setImageResource(getItem(position).getBookCoverResID());
    else
        bookCover.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return tempView;
}
}
```

This is code from MainActivity inside onCreate

```
ListView listView;
ArrayList<CardItem> cardItems = new ArrayList<>();
cardItems.add(new CardItem("Origin", "Dan Brown", "Completed"));
    cardItems.add(new CardItem("A Column of Fire"));
    cardItems.add(new CardItem("People vs Alex Cross", "James Patterson",
            "Completed", R.raw.people_vs_alex_cross));

    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(new CardItemAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, cardItems));
```

**The android app always crashes at startup giving me the OutOfMemoryError at getView() method of adapter in the setImageResourceID.** 
The app works fine without that if/else statement.
*The image i am using is a .jpg file stored in res\raw folder.*

Comment: Start by putting the image in a suitable `drawable` directory, either based on the target screen density of the image, or in `drawable-anydpi` if you want to use it for any screen density. If the problem continues, consider reducing the resolution of the image.

Comment: Alright so moving the image to drawable didnt work but thanks for pointing that out, but it turns out the image was indeed high resolution (1536x2344) so changing the image worked. Thanks a lot for the assist. Reply it as an answer so i can close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of images in `res/raw/` is not well-documented. I recommend putting images in drawable resource directories. If you want to use the same image across all screen densities, use `res/drawable-anydpi/`.

Beyond that, make sure that your image has a reasonable resolution. The amount of memory used by the image is a function of the resolution, not the on-disk size. For example, a 1536 x 2344 pixel image will consume 4 * 1536 * 2344 bytes = 14,401,536 bytes = ~14MB. It is unlikely that you will have a contiguous free block of memory that large.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
android:largeHeap=true
```

In manifest application tag